# MySQL - cant get the right order_by and group_by in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
select comment_id , section_name , comment , solution_part , display_order from 
solution_sections 
left join suggested_solution_comments on 
solution_sections.solution_section_id = suggested_solution_comments.solution_part and problem_id = 400
order by display_order;
```

What I wanted back was the all items (even null) returned ordered by the display_order column and if some have the same display_order, then those should be ordered by comment_id

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something, `order by display_order, comment_id` should give you what you want

Comment: Actually that worked...I was just getting mixed up in the results. Thanks for the advice. :)